# Displaying PDF file in fragments

Tags: android, pdf, android-fragments

I have to display a PDF file that has about 15 pages. I need to display the PDF file in a fragment and change pages every few seconds. I have several questions: 1)what do I use to display the PDF file (PDFTron, MuPDF or AndroidPDF), 2)is it free to use the PDF tools and 3) how do I implement changing pages? Still quite new to Android development and have a difficult task ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You can convert PDF into images and show em by fragments.

2) commercial tool

3) You can subscribe to file system event or if it is a stream based PDF you should find aspecific solution for your project.

Comment: Thanks for the response.That's exactly what I did. I converted them to images using "Automator" on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in Android specific to PDFs, so you'll want to look for a third-party java library to include in your project. As for displaying the pages, I would consider using a [`ViewPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and a [`PagerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I converted the PDF files to images. I will look at ViewPager and PageAdapter for displaying.